# import image in Prestashop with a website URL

Tags: csv, prestashop

I have a website on which my all products are display and all product images are save on this website server.
my new website making in prestashop on another server. I have a csv file which make according to prestashop. in this csv file images fill like :  http://example.net/images/demo.jpg
Like this.

when we import this csv file in prestoshop when this image link is save in prestashop db.
 and our image are display from that server on my new website server. I want to save my images on old server but also display on website.

so please help us how to we import this file in prestashop with image url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to do it easily. When you import a CSV file, PS copies the image from the URL to it's server, then it has to make copies of this image in different sizes, in other words prepare the image in it's own standards/configuration.

If you really really need this, you may try to override `Link::getProductImage` and similar functions (there may be more than one) to return product image URL from another server, but would have to be able to reconstruct the image URL from the information that you have on PS. For example, reference code. http://example.net/images/product/reference_1.jpg